# i am having problems with this operation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hello guys im trying to work out the follow operation with no success:

$\left[\frac{x+5}{\left(x-9\right)\left(x+9\right)}+\frac{x+7}{\left(x-9\right)^2}\right]\cdot \left(\frac{x-9}{x-3}\right)^2+\frac{7+x}{9+x}$

why? thanks.

i tried to solve it but i got some errors. Book says result is 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the book, if you change the fraction $\frac{x-9}{x-3}$ into $\frac{x-9}{x+3}$ in the OP, then

$$\frac{x+5}{\left(x-9\right)\left(x+9\right)}+\frac{x+7}{\left(x-9\right)^2}=\frac{(x+5)(x-9)+(x+7)(x+9)}{\left(x-9\right)^2\left(x+9\right)} = \frac{x^2-4x-45+x^2+16x+63}{\left(x-9\right)^2\left(x+9\right)}=\frac{2(x^2+6x+9)}{\left(x-9\right)^2\left(x+9\right)}=\frac{2(x+3)^2}{\left(x-9\right)^2\left(x+9\right)}$$

So
$$\left[\frac{x+5}{\left(x-9\right)\left(x+9\right)}+\frac{x+7}{\left(x-9\right)^2}\right]\cdot \left(\frac{x-9}{x+3}\right)^2+\frac{7+x}{9+x} = \frac{2(x+3)^2}{\left(x-9\right)^2\left(x+9\right)}\cdot \frac{(x-9)^2}{(x+3)^2}+\frac{7+x}{9+x}=\frac{2}{(x+9)}+\frac{7+x}{9+x}= \frac{9+x}{x+9}=1$$

Comment: Now everything is clear thanks